# Google redirect

Tags: google, redirects

When users try to access my site by typing it into Google or other search engines, they are redirected to a spammy abercrombie & fitch site.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is hacked. Somewhere, probably in your root .htaccess file, is code that checks to see if a user is coming from a search engine and redirecting them to the spam site. You need to fix that code and then address the security vulnerability in your software or server to prevent it from happening again. If you're using packaged software like Joomla, you will need to make sure you are running the latest version. If you wrote the software, you will need to check your log and see if you can find any suspicious activity.